# tailwindcss not using bg-white inside md breakpoint

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am wondering why tailwindcss is not using my md:bg-white when the screen size is between md and lg.

```
<div className={`h-12 bg-blue flex w-full text-white fixed mt-1 lg:bg-white md:bg-white ${scrolling ? 'md:animationNav  md:h-16' : 'md:animationBasisNav md:h-20'} md:dark:bg-gray-400`}>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `inside the md`? Also, for `md` to work, your minimum width has to be 768px.

Comment: i'm setting my screensize inside the md breakpoint so 768px

Comment: What background colour are you seeing at `md` breakpoint? Seems to work fine for me. Btw, `bg-blue` is not a valid background colour, you need to specify a number for it, e.g, `bg-blue-500`.

Comment: Not sure why you set `lg:bg-white md:bg-white`. It should be sufficient to set `md:bg-white`.

Comment: @juliomalves I set a different standard blue inside de tailwind.config.js. why would bg-blue not work and bg-white does? I can see my color being used

Comment: @dotcs I just added it to be sure that everything above xs would be bg-white